# Handling binned feature

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I am new to the field of data science and trying to figure out ways to handle data quality issues before performing any modeling.

I am working on a house rental price data set. In this data there is feature called **Total Squarefeet**. The issue I am facing here is that out of 12000 records 200 have a range, for e.g., 1200 - 1800, OR 850 - 855, OR even and these ranges also have a random difference between them. Rest other are simple numbers. Is there a way to correctly handle this kind of data. Can anyone help me or guide me to a place from where i can learn and use techniques to handle such data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column you are using must be of string data type. First filter the dataset where it contain "-" and create another dataframe. On this new dataframe perform split string operation and create two different column and convert them to integer. Now create another column which has average or whatever you prefer with two column. Rename column and drop unnecessary columns.  Merge it back to dataframe.